# using a loop in the constructor - java

Tags: java, constructor

I'm a novice programmer. I'm trying to create a class that accepts a String a returns a rational number, I'm planning to use this class to do basic math calculations (+-*/). I set my fields public and added a constructor that accepts a string and then tests if a number is decimal or not, converting it to rational if it is a decimal and leaving it the same if it is not. However, when I try to compile, I get this error: "Class, interface or enum expected" I check my {} and they all seem to be in place.. Here's my code

```
import java.lang.*; 
public class RationalNumbers{

    double numarator; 
    double denominator; 

    public RationalNumbers (String(val)){
        numerator = Integer.parseInt(val); 
        for (int i = 1; i< val.length(); i++){
            if(Val.charAt(i) == '.'){
                numerator = Math.round((numerator * Math.pow(10,(numeratorAsString.length() - (i+ 1))))); 
                denominator =  Math.pow(10,(numeratorAsString.length() - (i+ 1)));

            }else {
                numerator = numarator * 1;
                denominator = 1; 
            }
        } 
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "(" + numarator + " " + denominator + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: I just figured out my bug.

Comment: import java.lang.*; 
public class RationalNumbers{

 double numerator; 
    double denominator; 
 
 public RationalNumbers (String val){
  numerator = Integer.parseInt(val); 
  for (int i = 1; i< val.length(); i++){
   if(val.charAt(i) == '.'){
    numerator = (numerator * Math.pow(10,(val.length() - (i+ 1)))); 
    denominator =  Math.pow(10,(val.length() - (i+ 1)));
    
   }else {
    numerator = numerator * 1;
    denominator = 1; 
   }
  } 
 }
 public String toString(){
  return "(" + numerator + " " + denominator + ")";
 }
}

Answer (score 5):

change `public RationalNumbers (String(val)){` to

```
public RationalNumbers (String val){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public RationalNumbers (String(val)){
```

should be declared like

```
public RationalNumbers(String val){
```

Answer (score 1):

`String(val)` don't wrap variable names in `()` , just say  `String val`